# SQL Select 10 records at a time and convert to XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I have table with, for example, 1000 rows. I need to take every 10 of them, convert to XML and then save to separate file per 10 rows.

The problem is that I don't have idea how to take every 10 rows from database, do my job and then take another 10.

Do I need to take ENTIRE Data, XML it and THEN divide to my files or is there any simple way?

Many thanks for answers.

Comment: What RDBMS (mysql, sql server, postgres, oracle, etc..)  are you using. What language are you using to interact with it (vb, php, c#, something else?)

Comment: I am using sql server, and I need to make only script or procedure to do that task, so T-SQL only i guess

Comment: easy way is you select all of your record and your can youse LINQ command to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously I am using one of my tables here, so replace as necessary for your table.
Also, you'll have to work out the saving to file.

Hope this helps.....

```
DECLARE @i int = 0

WHILE @i < 9 --replace 9 as necessary - probably rowcount / 10
BEGIN

  SELECT (Q._Row / 10) as myGroup, Q.[Type], Q.[Message] FROM
  (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AuditLogId DESC) AS _Row, 
    [Type], [Message]   
  FROM tblAuditLog
  ) Q  
  WHERE (Q._Row / 10) = 0
  FOR XML AUTO

  --SAVE THAT XML somewhere

  set @I = @I + 1
END
```

Comment: exacly what i wanted to do, excellent work. Thanks. Now I only need to save it to file